# How to include a class file in another file in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, class, import

OK, the question seems to have already been asked, but it hasn't as is, some ask to include file in another, some ask to import functions, some accept jquery...
I'm working only in pure javascript, my files (simplified but still doesn't work):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="Content-Type" content="UTF-8">
    <script src='editable.js'></script>
    <script src='global.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
```

global.js

```
window.addEventListener('load',Init);

function Init()
{
    var test=new Editable();    //this throw a undefined Element error
}
```

editable.js

```
export class Editable
{
    constructor()
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using it in some html pages ?

Comment: It is surprisingly straight forward: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Standard_Import

Comment: @Cid yes I do Cid

Comment: @Stuart the bracket after import throws an syntax error. I already tried.

Comment: Mayeb post the full code you are using, the html, where you are including the JS, where ts called, where it is defined, etc -- so we can see your actual setup, and where this syntax error is originating! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "include" it directly from HTML, such as :

```
<script src="YourClassFile.js"></script>
<script src="YourScriptThatUsesTheClass.js"></script>
```

Comment: Finally after turning the things in all the ways it works, with the simplest way. Sorry I don't understand what I did wrong the first time.

Comment: You may have inverted the order of the class file with the script one (if the script is read before the class definition you'll get an error since the class is not yet defined)